# select query to sum average fields from table1 and count field from table

Tags: mysql, vb.net-2010

Table: scores

```
Judge   No      Name    Casual  Barong  Talent  Swimsuit    Formal                  
Judge1  Ginoo 1 John    85      85      85      85          85                  
Judge2  Ginoo 1 John    84      86      88      82          83                  
Judge3  Ginoo 1 John    90      86      84      87          87                  
Judge1  Ginoo 2 David   85      85      85      85          85                  
Judge2  Ginoo 2 David   89      81      83      84          85                  
Judge3  Ginoo 2 David   87      84      83      87          88
```

Table: textvote

```
No      Sender                                  
Ginoo 1 9307895654                                      
Ginoo 1 9566551234                                      
Ginoo 1 9232235643                                      
Ginoo 2 9225557878
```

Query Result

```
Rank     No      Name  Casual Barong Talent Swimsuit Formal Textvote Total      
Champion Ginoo 1 John  86.33  85.67  85.67  84.67    85.00  93.75   86.73           
1stRunup Ginoo 2 David 87.00  83.33  83.67  85.33    86.00  81.25   84.32           
2ndRunup
```

This is my latest code:

```
"SELECT s.no, s.name, AVG(s.casual) AS Casual, AVG(s.barong) AS Barong, AVG(s.swimsuit) AS Swimsuit, AVG(s.formal) AS Formal, " & _
                "(select count(*) / (select count(*) from (textvote) where no like '%Ginoo%') * (100 / count(*)) + (100 - (100 / count(*))) AS 'Text Vote', " & _
                "(AVG(s.casual) * 0.15) + (AVG(s.barong) * 0.25) + (AVG(s.swimsuit) * 0.15) + (AVG(s.formal) * 0.15) + " & _
                "(select count(*) / (select count(*) from (textvote) where no like '%Ginoo%') * (100 / count(*)) + (100 - (100 / count(*))) * 0.15 AS Total  " & _
                "FROM scores s " & _
                "INNER JOIN textvote t ON s.no = t.no " & _
                "WHERE t.no LIKE '%Ginoo%' " & _
                "GROUP BY t.no"
```

I got this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near " at line 1

Comment: Do you have separate column for `textvote`? It is missing in your sample data

Comment: your textvote % doesn't make sense, how do you get 93% from 3 out of 4 votes?

Comment: Yes 3 out of 4 votes. 3/4 * (100/4) + (100 - (100/4))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until I know how your calculating `textvote` I have left `textvotecalc` blank (fill in yourself):

```
SELECT s.candidate, AVG(s.gown) AS "gown 30%",
AVG(s.talent) AS "talent 30%",
?textvotecalc? AS "textvote 40% ",
((AVG(s.gown)*100)/30) + ((AVG(s.talent)*100)/30)  + ((?textvotecalc?*100)/40) AS TOTAL
FROM scores s
INNER JOIN textvote t ON s.candidate = t.candidate
GROUP BY s.candidate
```

**EDIT:**

You had an extra `)` at the end of the `TOTAL` calculation.

```
SELECT s.no, s.name, AVG(s.casual) AS Casual, AVG(s.barong) AS Barong, AVG(s.swimsuit) AS Swimsuit, AVG(s.formal) AS Formal,
(COUNT(t.no) / " & TextVoteCountGinoo & ") * (" & TextVoteCountGinoo & " - COUNT(t.no)) + (" & TextVoteCountGinoo & " - (" & TextVoteCountGinoo & " - COUNT(t.no))) AS'Text Vote',
(AVG(s.casual) * 0.15) + (AVG(s.barong) * 0.25) + (AVG(s.swimsuit) * 0.15) + (AVG(s.formal) * 0.15) + (COUNT(t.no) / " & TextVoteCountGinoo & ") * (100 / " & TextVoteCountGinoo & ") + (100 - (100 / " & TextVoteCountGinoo & ") ) * 0.15 AS Total
FROM scores s 
INNER JOIN textvote t ON s.no = t.no 
WHERE s.no LIKE '%Ginoo%' 
GROUP BY s.no
```

In your VB format:

```
SELECT s.no, s.name, AVG(s.casual) AS Casual, AVG(s.barong) AS Barong, AVG(s.swimsuit) AS Swimsuit, AVG(s.formal) AS Formal, & _
"(COUNT(t.no) / " & TextVoteCountGinoo & ") * (" & TextVoteCountGinoo & " - COUNT(t.no)) + (" & TextVoteCountGinoo & " - (" & TextVoteCountGinoo & " - COUNT(t.no))) AS'Text Vote'," & _
"(AVG(s.casual) * 0.15) + (AVG(s.barong) * 0.25) + (AVG(s.swimsuit) * 0.15) + (AVG(s.formal) * 0.15) +" & _ "(COUNT(t.no) / " & TextVoteCountGinoo & ") * (100 / " & TextVoteCountGinoo & ") + (100 - (100 / " & TextVoteCountGinoo & ") ) * 0.15 AS Total" & _
"FROM scores s 
INNER JOIN textvote t ON s.no = t.no 
WHERE s.no LIKE '%Ginoo%' 
GROUP BY s.no"
```

Comment: Thank you Matt for immediate help. I will try this one.

Comment: I got this error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corressponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near
'scores s inner join textvote t on s.no = t.no where s.no like '%Ginoo%' group b' at line 1

Comment: Now I get this error; 'scores s INNER JOIN textvote t ON s.no = t.no WHERE s.no LIKE '%Ginoo%' GROUP BY s'

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'scores s INNER JOIN textvote t ON s.no = t.no WHERE s.no LIKE '%Ginoo%' GROUP BY s' at line 1

Comment: Use the 2nd query i posted and then convert it to VB syntax

Comment: I got this You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'scores sINNER JOIN textvote t ON s.no=t.noWHERE s.no LIKE '%Ginoo%'GROUP BY s.' at line 1

Comment: looks like there isnt spaces between words

Comment: Kudos... I don't believe it it works. thank you so much. Matt.

Comment: Hi Matt, Sorry for inconvenience, I have edited my question above. This is my latest code to completely show the results I needed. Can you please check it.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near " at line 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134073/discussion-between-lughen-and-matt).